# HTA to read a text file and populate drop down box

Tags: text, drop-down-menu, vbscript, populate, hta

A text file example will include the following data, a name and associated IP address, in this format:

```
name;IP
```

i.e.

```
harry;192.168.1.14
billy;192.168.1.22
```

Using VBS to read the text file and split the data into 2 parts:

```vb
Sub LoadDropDownName
    Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  'Creating a File Object
    Const ForReading = 1                    'Defining Constant Value to read from a file
    Set obj1 = obj.OpenTextFile("savedhosts.txt", ForReading) 'Opening a text file and reading text from it
    Dim str, str1
    str = obj1.ReadAll                      'All text from the file is read using ReadAll
    MsgBox str                              'Contents of a file will be displayed through message box
    'Do While obj1.AtEndofStream            'Reading text line wise using Do Loop and ReadLine
    '    str1 = obj1.ReadLine
    '    MsgBox str1
    'Loop
    Do Until obj1.AtEndOfStream
        strNextLine = obj1.ReadLine
        arrServiceList = Split(strNextLine, ";")
        Set objOption = document.CreateElement("OPTION")
        objOption.title = arrServiceList(0)
        objOption.value = arrServiceList(1)
        LoadDropDownName.Add(objOption)
        MsgBox "arrServiceList(0) = " & arrServiceList(0)
        MsgBox "arrServiceList(1) = " & arrServiceList(1)
    Loop
    'MsgBox ""        
    obj1.Close                              'Closing a File
    Set obj = Nothing                       'Releasing File object    
End Sub
```

`MsgBox str` works as it displays all the data from the "savedhosts.txt" file as expected.

However I cant get

```vb
MsgBox "arrServiceList(0) = " & arrServiceList(0)
MsgBox "arrServiceList(1) = " & arrServiceList(1)
```

to display in a box. I have moved the `MsgBox` command to below the `Loop` line.

```vb
Loop
MsgBox "arrServiceList(0) = " & arrServiceList(0)
MsgBox "arrServiceList(1) = " & arrServiceList(1)
'MsgBox ""      
obj1.Close                              'Closing a File
Set obj = Nothing                       'Releasing File object
```

I received an error:

> Type mismatch 'arrServiceList'

The HTML part that should capture the data from the `Sub`:

```html
<input type='text' maxlength="15" class="enterhostip" id="INPUT-IP" name='text1'/>
```

INPUT IP: user can input a new IP and will auto change when 'Saved Hostname' has chosen a new value.

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="20" name="hostname" id="hostname" />
```

Hostname: user can input a new name for the host

```html
<select id="savedhostname" maxlength="20" name="savedhostname" onchange="vbscript:LoadDropDownName" class="pwhost" />
```

Saved Hostname: dropdown data showing only the name in the savedhosts.txt file. Changing the name will execute the
`LoadDropDownName` script and change the value of "IP-Input".

If someone can show me an example of similar code (using VBScript) to read the contents of this text file and show the names only in a html drop down box while using a html single line text input area to auto fill the associated IP address?

I have searched for an example of this method but cannot find any that meet this simple criteria!

Comment: What do you mean "example of this method"? This is a combination of 3 fairly basic operations: a) read a file, b) populate a dropdown list, and c) update a text field with the selection from the dropdown list. Please do some research and try writing some code first. SO is not a free code-writing service.

Comment: "example of this method" means i have failed to find a similar example using search facilities. If anyone can show me an example of such a code then I can manipulate it into my own custom code. I am not asking for a full solution, nor am I asking for free help. I'm sure there is some sort of working example somwhere, I just haven't found it.

Comment: Break it down into it’s component parts or do you just want a quick fix and not interested in learning? It’s 3 steps, 1. Read text file (hundreds of examples), 2. Parse the content (delimited list, array lot's of ways of doing this type of operation) and 3. Display parsed data as a HTML dropdown (again a common operation, use a `For` loop to populate the HTML select `options`. Plenty of examples of this type as well). Unfortunately finding those all in one handy ready to use script isn’t likely but that’s the difference between a “quick fix” and actually learning something. Good luck.

Comment: I am interested in learning so I can adapt and configure accordingly. Quick fix means I will learn nothing and not understand the line by line function of the scripts.. I have tried to create a basic model of the solution, please check ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue might be that you read the whole file (I suspect for debugging purposes) which ends the stream, and then `obj.AtEndOfStream` becomes `true`. Therefore your loop doesn't execute.

```vb
  str=obj1.ReadAll ' ends the stream
```

You could close then reopen the stream

```
Set obj1 = obj.OpenTextFile("savedhosts.txt", ForReading) 'Opening a text file and reading text from it
Dim str,str1
str=obj1.ReadAll                        'All text from the file is read using ReadAll
Msgbox str
obj1.Close
Set obj1 = obj.OpenTextFile("savedhosts.txt", ForReading) ' etc
```

or just omit the `obj1.ReadAll` bit, or process `str` as one big chunk of text

Comment: i didn't know you could do that on a Textstream

Comment: Good point you can’t, was thinking of an `ADODB.Stream` not the `TextStream` object.